# ngrx: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using ngrx/effects.

After updating **rxjs** from **5.0.0-beta.12** to **5.0.0-rc.1**, my IDE WebStorm gives me the error below (red underline). And when I run my app, the same error also shows in the terminal.

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

[image]

```
  @Effect() updateProfile$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ProfileActions.PROFILE_UPDATE_PROFILE)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .switchMap(name => this.profileService.updateProfile(name)
      .map(name => ({ type: ProfileActions.PROFILE_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS, payload: name }))
      .catch(error => Observable.of({ type: ProfileActions.PROFILE_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL, payload: error }))
    );
```

.

```
  updateProfile(name: string): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.of(name);
  }
```

- This error happens whenever I use `map<string>(toPayload)`. I tried to change to `.map<any>(action => action.payload)`, but still same error.
- The effects without `map<string>(toPayload)` won't give the
  error.

Although it gives me the error, the app still runs well.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In rxjs 5.0.0-rc.1 the generic type parameters for all operators were changed to accept the type of the source observable first.

You will need to change the `map` operator call accordingly:

```
actions$
  .ofType(ProfileActions.PROFILE_UPDATE_PROFILE)
  .map<Action, string>(toPayload)
```

Comment: Just add Mike's words from Gitter, `Action` is from `import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';`. Or `.map< ProfileActions, string>(toPayload)` works too.